# How to find the data-id in watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to watir testing. Would somebody help me to find the following element.

```
<div class="location_picker_type_level" data-loc-type="1">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

I like to find this `div`, `data-loc-type` with `table` exists.

### ex:

```
browser.elements(:xpath,"//div[@class='location_picker_type_section[data-loc-type='1']' table ]").exists?
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Watir supports using `data-` type attributes as locators (ie no need to use xpath). Simply replace the dashes with underscores and add a colon to the start.

You can get the div using the following (note the format of the locator for the attribute: data-loc-type -> :data_loc_type ):

```
browser.div(:class => 'location_picker_type_level', :data_loc_type => '1')
```

If it is only expected that there is one div of this type, you can check that it has a table by doing:

```
div = browser.div(:class => 'location_picker_type_level', :data_loc_type => '1')
puts div.table.exists?
#=> true
```

If there are multiple divs that match and you want to check that at least one of them has the table, use the `any?` method for a `divs` collection:

```
#Get a collection of all div tags matching the criteria
divs = browser.divs(:class => 'location_picker_type_level', :data_loc_type => '1')

#Check if the table exists in any of the divs
puts divs.any?{ |d| d.table.exists? }
#=> true

#Or if you want to get the div that contains the table, use 'find'
div = divs.find{ |d| d.table.exists? }
```

Comment: Thank you very much not only for the answer.. You explained me very well. I really appreciate you. You are the man... !

Comment: One more doubt. Its like a accordion. It should return true only its expanded. is it any way to find this thing?

Comment: Short answer is yes. How would depend on the implementation. If the table is only displayed when expanded, then you should change the `table.exists?` to `table.present?` (which checks that the table exists in the html and is visible to the user).

Comment: When did we add the support for :data_xxx selection specifiers?  that's awesome, I thought we had to monkeypatch that in..  (off to modify my code)

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden, watir-classic had it added in (version 3)[http://watir.com/2012/04/24/watir-3-released/]. For watir-webdriver it looks to be about the same time.