# Watir: How do i get inner_html of multiple span, with same class name

Tags: html, ruby, watir

I am using this code, to grab the `inner_html` of the span class.

```
weather = browser.span(:class => "_Xbe kno-fv").inner_html
puts weather
```

However, Multiple `inner_html` exists with the same class, in the page. How do I retrieve all of them at once?

I am trying to get the information relating to weather from this [page](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=w7-YWN75OsyAoAPK_oDYBQ#q=bangalore)

```
weather = browser.span(:class => "_Xbe kno-fv").text
puts weather
```

This above code, prints, the text but not consistently. I beleive, since multiple elements exists with the same class or the information is dynamic and hence? I am not sure. Is there a way to get this?
4

**Result in the first run**

```
Examples:
  | Search    |
  | Bangalore |  741&nbsp;km²
```

**Result in the second run**

```
Examples:
  | Search    |
  | Bangalore |  17°C, Wind E at 3 km/h, 69% Humidity
```

Comment: Try browser.spans() instead of browser.span()

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, I had forgot to mention, I did try `browser.spans`. I get this printed in the result  `#<Watir::SpanCollection:0x2ff6118>`

Comment: @Raphael Ahhh! I found this didnt work since I hadnt given any iterator. This worked

`weather = browser.spans(:class => "").each do |span|`

`puts span.text`

Thank you!

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS, I have a scenario where all the <span> will not have any class, randomly have id and common xpath. how can I use this spans method with xpath to retrieve multiple span elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element that you are targeting is contained within a `<div>` with a unique data attribute.  I'd advise using that approach:

```
require 'watir'    
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=w7-YWN75OsyAoAPK_oDYBQ#q=bangalore" 

puts b.div(:data_attrid => "kc:/location/citytown:current weather").text
#=> Weather: 59°F (15°C), Wind S at 2 mph (3 km/h), 83% Humidity
```

For reference--as @JustinKo [demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570995/how-to-find-the-data-id-in-watir)--`watir` can use data attributes as locators with some minor tweaks.

Sidenote: running automated searches against Google may be a violation of their Terms of Service, and you may find yourself blocked.  You should investigate if you can use one of their many APIs to harvest this data.

Comment: Thanks @orde . This works good... and about the sidenote, I didn't know, this, but why? I thought only scraping websites required permissions? but anyway, google should be having a benchmark, to declare my searches to be automated ? like 1000 searches per second?

Comment: I'm not sure how strict they are in terms of allowing automated searches.  Just a warning that they may not like it ;)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the cause of your problem, but one significant issue is that you are using multiple class values when a class locator can only accept one:

Don't do this: `browser.span(:class => "_Xbe kno-fv")`

Do this: `browser.span(css: "._Xbe.kno-fv")`